# Trying to calculate amount in jQuery to then insert it into an HTML <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Background info: I need to take the number of participants registered and multiply it by 11. The CMS internal tag will pull the data for me, I just need to insert the end value that I need automatically without having to change it everytime a new person registers.

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #c94779;" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #c94779; color: #ffffff; padding-left: 14px; padding-top: 8px; width: 100%; height: 28px; font-family: Rockwell; font-size: 1.357em; text-transform: uppercase;">Thank you!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 14px; padding-top: 3px;" valign="top">
<p><span class="subheading">The hard work of our Ambassadors is paying off</span></p>
<p><strong>Total Women Educated:</strong> <strong>[[C1:sponsor_2]]</strong></p>
<p id="womenreached">  </p>
<p><strong>Fundraising Total:</strong> <strong><convio:session name="42" param="0:dollars"></convio:session></strong></p>
<p><strong>Number of Ambassadors:</strong> <strong><convio:session name="42" param="0:num-participants"></convio:session></strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var reached = '';
   var participants = '[[S42:15793:num-participants]]';
   var women =  'participants * 11';
   if (women) {
       reached = women;
      }
   else {
       reached = 0;
      }  
    jQuery('#womenreached p').html("Total Women Reached: " + reached);
});
```

The S42 tag I'm using in `var participants` is the custom tag that the CMS system will pull the data with. I noticed it wasn't working at all when the part "Total Women Reached: " wasn't being inserted at all.

I tried to do it in jsfiddle and replaced the s42 tag with `var participants = '600'` and it doesn't work either. I tried to read the document but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the quotes. Assuming the CMS value is numerical, remove the quotes around the `participants` value and also around the calculation you're doing.

Also note that your `if` statement is pretty redundant too, as the value will already be `0` in the else case when you set it to `0`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var participants = [[S42:15793:num-participants]]; // assuming this value comes from server
   var women = participants * 11;
   $('#womenreached').text("Total Women Reached: " + women);
});
```

Working example:

```js
var participants = 600;
var women = participants * 11;
console.log("Total Women Reached: " + women);
```

Comment: Thanks for super quick response Rory, you're correct the value does come from server and it is a numerical value once displayed. The working example works perfect, but for some reason I still can't seem to insert the `.html` part into the `p` tag.

Comment: Ah - that's because the `#womenreached` element *is* the `p` tag, so you don't need ' p' at the end of the selector. I updated the answer for you

Comment: ah perfect! Thanks so much Rory, I been banging my head against the wall. Ok so to note for next time, if its numerical values, do not use quotes? and if the `id` being used is the actual tag for `.html`, declaring isn't required ? *i have to wait 5 minutes to mark as answer lol*

Comment: That's right. Quotes denote string values which are more tricky to perform mathematical operations on. With regard to the selector, it follows CSS rules, so the space meant it was looking for a `p` element which was the child of `#womenreached`, which didn't exist

Comment: And no problem, glad to help :)